# Why Are My Instantiated Prefab Clones Not Rendering In Game View After Previous Instantiations Succeeded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a small 2D game called "Protect the Square", whereas the name suggests the player must protect a square from circular enemies via powerups, controlling the square itself, and controlling a paddle used to deflect the enemies. I am currently working on an endless mode, where the level is continuously generated from handmade prefabs as the player progresses through it, but I am running into an issue. After 4 to 5 segments(prefabs) are instantiated successfully, future segments, while still being instantiated, are invisible in the game view. This feature is still a work in progress, so I only have two prefab segments at the moment, and at the beginning of the level, both prefabs instantiate correctly, but after the 4 to 5 segment threshold is reached, the same prefabs which were previously instantiating correctly become invisible. Once this happens to one prefab it happens to all future prefabs, but collisions still work as expected. Despite being invisible in the game view, the prefabs appear normal in the editor. I have tried saving my game and restarting Unity, but other than that, I'm clueless about what is causing this or how to troubleshoot and fix it. I have included my level generation script below, although I doubt that the script is the problem because even the problematic prefabs are instantiated in the correct positions.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
     
    public class LevelSpawner : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject[] levelPrefabs; // Array of level prefabs
        public Transform square; // Reference to the square object
        public float triggerDistance; // Distance at which to trigger the next level piece
        public Transform startingSpawnPoint; // Spawn point of the starting piece
     
        private Transform lastSpawnPoint; // Last spawn point
     
        void Start()
        {
            lastSpawnPoint = startingSpawnPoint;
        }
     
        void Update()
        {
            // Check if the square is close enough to the last spawn point to trigger the next level piece
            if (Vector2.Distance(square.position, lastSpawnPoint.position) <= triggerDistance)
            {
                // Select a random level prefab
                int index = Random.Range(0, levelPrefabs.Length);
                GameObject levelPrefab = levelPrefabs[index];
     
                // Determine the position for instantiating the new level piece
                Vector3 spawnPosition = lastSpawnPoint.position;
     
                // Instantiate the level prefab at the spawn position
                GameObject newLevelPiece = Instantiate(levelPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
     
                // Update the last spawn point
                lastSpawnPoint = newLevelPiece.transform.Find("SpawnPoint");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is having the same issue as I was: My problem was that the scale of my game was too large. You can start to have issues if your objects are greater than 10,000 units away from the origin, so you need to try to stay within that range. I myself wasn't having an issue until I got to about 30,000 units away from the origin, and 4 to 5 of my level segments just happened to be the number it took to get out that far. So, in short, if you're having a similar issue check your transform position and make sure it's not above 10K units on any axis!